# Rails 4: How to manipulate params in a api controller before create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create an API in Rails 4 application to allow another application to create records. The records are created based on what the other application knows, but the actual data which needs to be saved is somewhat different. I need to manipulate params before they are used to create a new record.

My model:

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :prod_code, type: String
  field :batch_id, type: BSON::ObjectId
  field :assy_lot_id, type: BSON::ObjectId
  field :assy_lot_sn, type: String 

  belongs_to :assy_lot
  belongs_to :batch
end
```

API controller

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ProductsController < ActionController::Base
      before_filter :restrict_access

      respond_to :json

      def create
        variant_id = Variant.find(variant: params[:product]["variant"]).first        
        assy_lot_id = AssyLot.find(assy_lot: params[:product]["assy_lot"],variant_id: variant_id).first

        params[:product][:prod_code]=params[:product]["variant"] + "-" + params[:product]["assy_lot"] + "-" + params[:product]["assy_lot_sn"]
        params[:product][:batch_id]=Batch.find(assy_lot_id: assy_lot_id).first
        params[:product][:assy_lot_id]=assy_lot_id

        params[:product].delete "variant"        

        respond_with Chip.create(params[:product])
      end

    private

      def restrict_access
        authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
          ApiKey.where(access_token: token).exists?
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I test the API with curl

```
curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/v1/chips.json -H 'Authorization:Token token="xxxxxxxxx"' -X POST -d '{"variant":"NA","assy_lot":"004","assy_lot_sn":"0001"}'
```

It connects OK, but I get

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

for any line where I try to access values in params like so `params[:product]["something"]`

Can somebody please point me to the right syntax, which will allow me to check values passed in params and change them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using curl command in wrong way. To pass data via curl you should write

```
curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/v1/chips.json -H 'Authorization:Token token="xxxxxxxxx"' -X POST -d "variant=NA&assy_lot=004&assy_lot_sn=0001"
```

This will sent params to rails as

```
{'variant': 'NA', 'assy_lot: 004', 'assy_lot_sn': '0001'}
```

This will allow you to access variant as `params['variant']` inside the controller.

If you want to access variant as `params[:product]["variant"]` inside controller, you would have to pass data as following in curl command.

```
curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/v1/chips.json -H 'Authorization:Token token="xxxxxxxxx"' -X POST -d "product[variant]=NA&product[assy_lot]=004&product[assy_lot_sn]=0001"
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the explanation on how to use it and test it. I used the second format.

Comment: Nice to hear that @BartC

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you send your request with the parameters on 'product'? Try this:

```
curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/v1/chips.json -H 'Authorization:Token token="xxxxxxxxx"' -X POST -d 'product: {"variant":"NA","assy_lot":"004","assy_lot_sn":"0001"}'
```

Comment: Thanks. I was definitely using curl the wrong way but also didn't know how to get the params correctly even if I submitted them OK. @Rohan's answer took me out of the dark :D